# How do I prevent multiple login in angular

Tags: angular, jwt, storage

We use backend .net core api frontend angular in our project. We send the api request and keep the user information in localstorage. How do we prevent multiple logins with the same user in different browsers or clients?

Comment: You have to control this in the back end. You would set a flag when a user logs in and deny other login attempts while that flag is active. There are all kinds of cases you would need to handle depending on your authentication mechanism. You've given very little information here, so you can't really expect a detailed answer at the moment.

Comment: I want when the second user log in, the first user to log out . Is it good to check the backend side when the user requests for each page?

Comment: You would only need to check at the point of logging in (and refreshing tokens if you're using refresh tokens). You can't trust anything in the browser - including local storage.

Comment: I am using jwt bearer token. I do not know about Flag and Token Refresh, I will research. Thanks for your help.

Comment: By flag I just mean some field that says whether or not the user is currently logged in. You would probably store something in the database to state whether the user is currently logged in. This is a complex scenario with a lot of moving parts. Good luck...

Answer (score 0):

I am not expert with .net, but you can store current time at every login and store in array the username. And then when someone login check if it is in array list. If, get difference between the time. For example if the difference is 10 or less minutes the log in is not accespted.

Comment: There is a problem when logging in from different clients.

Comment: You should store log users in database. Then when make some cycle. And when someone else log you remove it from database and the cycle will log him off.